# Multiple MAX() functions with different condition for each

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

How can I select multiple MAX() but just when conditions are met.

Pseudocode which explains what I need to do

```
SELECT
  MAX(level, WHERE strength >= 100) m1,
  MAX(level, WHERE strength < 100) m2 
FROM players
WHERE premium_account = 1
```

Do I need a subquery, or is there a place to use `CASE WHEN`?
I don't want to split it into separate queries, because my "master" query filters a lot of uneccessary rows and limits the search to the small subset of whole table.

The table is very big, having about 13M of rows and taking 6GB of disk space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CASE` inside of `MAX`

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN strength >= 100 THEN level END) m1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN strength < 100 THEN level END) m2
FROM players
WHERE premium_account = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
MAX(IF(strength >= 100, level, 0))
```

Substitute 0 with a lower number if necessary.